# Tengo un problema con mi ArrayList ¿cómo pasar ArrayList de clases en clases?

Tags: java, array, arraylist

Tengo este código:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class ManejadorUsuario{
    ArrayList<Usuario> arregloUsuario=new ArrayList<Usuario>();
    
    public void autentificacion(){
        ObtenerDatos oD=new ObtenerDatos();
        InterfazAdministrador iAdministrador=new InterfazAdministrador();
        InterfazCajero iCajero=new InterfazCajero();
        ManejadorUsuario mUsuario=new ManejadorUsuario();
        
        String nick;
        String pass;
        String rol;
        int lock=0;
        
        do{
            for(int i=0; i<=(arregloUsuario.size()); i++){
                System.out.println("Usuario:");
                nick=oD.texto();
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("Contraseña:");
                pass=oD.texto();
                System.out.println("");

                if((arregloUsuario.get(i).getNick().equals(nick))&&(arregloUsuario.get(i).getPass().equals(pass))){
                    if(arregloUsuario.get(i).getRol()=="A"){
                        System.out.println("Administrador");
                        System.out.println("///////////////////////////////////////////////////");
                        iAdministrador.uiAdmin();
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("Cajero");
                        System.out.println("///////////////////////////////////////////////////");
                        iCajero.uiCajero();
                    }
    
                }else{
                    System.out.println("Contraseña y/o usuario incorrecto(s)");
                    System.out.println("");
                    System.out.println("");
                }
            }

        }while(lock!=1);
        
    }
```

> Es básicamente un login que toma los objetos Usuario de mi ArrayList arregloUsuario. Entonces para que funcione al iniciarlo le coloco esto:

```
public class Principal{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        ManejadorUsuario mUsuario=new ManejadorUsuario();
        ObtenerDatos oD=new ObtenerDatos();
        
        String nick;
        String pass;
        String rol;
        int idU;
        
        //Agregando administrador.
        nick="Admin";
        pass="admin123";
        rol="A";
        mUsuario.agregarUsuario(nick, pass, rol);
        
        mUsuario.autentificacion();
    }
}
```

> En donde el método agregarUsuario de mi clase Manejador usuario es esta:

```
public void agregarUsuario(String nick, String pass, String rol){
        arregloUsuario.add(new Usuario(nick, pass, rol));
    }
```

> Esa clase la uso exclusivamente para agregar un objeto al inicio y pueda hacer el login efectivamente.
> Tengo otra clase llamada InterfazAdministrador, en dónde llama al método ingresarUsuario, pero ese método esta en la clase ManejadorUsuario y este es el método:

```
public void ingresarUsuario(){
        ObtenerDatos oD=new ObtenerDatos();
        String nick;
        String pass;
        String rol;
        
        int yn;
        int contUs=0;
        
        do{
            System.out.println("Ingrese un usuario");
            nick=oD.texto();
            System.out.println("Ingrese una contraseña");
            pass=oD.texto();
            System.out.println("Ingrese el rol");
            System.out.println("Si desea el rol de administrador solo escriba [A]");
            System.out.println("Si desea el rol de cajero solo escriba [C]");
            rol=oD.texto();
            arregloUsuario.add(new Usuario(nick, pass, rol));
            System.out.println("");
            contUs++;
            
            System.out.println("Mostrando usuario...");
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Usuario: "+arregloUsuario.get(contUs-1).getNick());
            System.out.println("Contraseña: "+arregloUsuario.get(contUs-1).getPass());
            System.out.println("Rol: "+arregloUsuario.get(contUs-1).getRol());              
            System.out.println("ID de usuario: "+(contUs));
            System.out.println("");
            
            System.out.println("Desea agregar otro usuario?");
            System.out.println("[1] Si");
            System.out.println("[2] No");
            yn=oD.numero();
            System.out.println("");
        }while(yn!=2);
    }
```

> Lo que hace el método es ingresar objetos Usuario al arregloUsuario, en dónde tengo otra opción para mostrarlos y si me los muestra correctamente.

En la clase InterfazAdministrador tengo el método uiAdmin, y en ese método tengo otra opción para regresar al login o más bien sale del método uiAdmin y reanuda el método autentificacion de la clase manejadorUsuario.

El problema viene ahora, cuando trato de hacer de nuevo el login no me deja porque me suelta este error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
        at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:657)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:433)
        at ManejadorUsuario.autentificacion(ManejadorUsuario.java:26)
        at Principal.main(Principal.java:17)
```

> La línea 26 de mi clase ManejadorUsuario en el metodo autentiiciacion en dónde ocurre el error es esta:

```
if((arregloUsuario.get(i).getNick().equals(nick))&&(arregloUsuario.get(i).getPass().equals(pass))){
```

> Lo que se puede decir es que al querer obtener la variable nick de esa posición y la variable pass de la misma no los toma porque no existen, lo que quiere decir que no esta tomando los cambios que yo realizo al ingresar objetos Usuario en mi ArrayList arregloUsuario. ¿Alguien sabe cómo solucionar mi error? soy bastante novato y he probado varios métodos en foros de ayuda, pero nada me sirve :(.

**EDITADO**

Clase interfazAdministrado, método uiAdmin:

```
public void uiAdmin(){
        ObtenerDatos oD=new ObtenerDatos();
        ManejadorCliente mCliente=new ManejadorCliente();
        ManejadorProducto mProducto=new ManejadorProducto();
        ManejadorUsuario mUsuario=new ManejadorUsuario();
        
        int opcionIA;
        int opcionClientes;
        int opcionProducto;
        int opcionUsuario;
        
        do{
            System.out.println("[1] Clientes");
            System.out.println("[2] Productos");
            System.out.println("[3] Usuarios");
            System.out.println("[4] Regresar al login");
            opcionIA=oD.numero();
            System.out.println("///////////////////////////////////////////////////");
            
            switch (opcionIA){
                case 1:{
                      //Omití case 1, ya que no es de importancia, no entra en el problema
                    }
                
                
                
                case 2:{
                      //Omití el case 2, ya que no era de importancia, no entra en el problema
                    }
                

                
                case 3:{
                    System.out.println("Usuarios");
                    System.out.println("");
                    do{
                        System.out.println("[1] Ingresar");
                        System.out.println("[2] Modificar");
                        System.out.println("[3] Eliminar");
                        System.out.println("[4] Buscar");
                        System.out.println("[5] Mostrar lista");
                        System.out.println("[6] Regresar");
                        opcionUsuario=oD.numero();
                        System.out.println("///////////////////////////////////////////////////");
                        
                        switch (opcionUsuario){
                            case 1:{
                                System.out.println("Ingresar");
                                System.out.println("");
                                mUsuario.ingresarUsuario();
                                System.out.println("///////////////////////////////////////////////////");
                            }break;
                            
                            case 2:{
                                System.out.println("Modificar");
                                System.out.println("");
                                mUsuario.modificarUsuario();
                                System.out.println("///////////////////////////////////////////////////");
                            }break;
                            
                            case 3:{
                                System.out.println("Eliminar");
                                System.out.println("");
                                mUsuario.eliminarUsuario();
                                System.out.println("///////////////////////////////////////////////////");
                            }break;
                            
                            case 4:{
                                System.out.println("Buscar");
                                System.out.println("");
                                mUsuario.buscarUsuario();
                                System.out.println("///////////////////////////////////////////////////");
                            }break;
                            
                            case 5:{
                                System.out.println("Mostrar lista");
                                System.out.println("");
                                mUsuario.mostrarUsuario();
                                System.out.println("///////////////////////////////////////////////////");
                            }break;
                        }
                        
                    }while(opcionUsuario!=6);
                }break;
                
            }
            
        }while(opcionIA!=4);
    }
```

Comment: ¿De casualidad tienes las clases en archivos diferentes?

Comment: Pues claro que sí.

Comment: Te recomiendo ser específico en el problema/duda que tienes y solo adjuntar el código que te está causando problemas. También, te recomiendo leer [como crear un ejemplo mínimo verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) y [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Saludos.

Comment: @Gabitohh, esta bien, pero mi problema no es una mala programación de código, más que todo es cómo usar la misma ArrayList en diferentes clases, porque la ArrayList manejadorUsuario la trabaja con diferentes datos en las clases, no toma los cambios que hice en otra clase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema está en la siguiente línea: `for(int i=0; i<=(arregloUsuario.size()); i++)`.

Suponiendo que en el `ArrayList` hay un solo elemento, la posición que ocupa es `0` pero el valor de `arregloUsuario.size()` es `1`. A establecer la condición para terminar el `for` en `<= arregloUsuario.size()` quiere decir que se ejecuta 2 veces, la primera vez `i = 0` y no hay problema, pero la segunda vez, `i = 1` y se produce el error porque solo hay un elemento.

La solución es cambiar la condición a `< arregloUsuario.size()`

Omito parte del código para mantener el foco en el área de interés

```
...
do{
    //             |
    //             V
    for(int i=0; i < (arregloUsuario.size()); i++){
        System.out.println("Usuario:");
        nick=oD.texto();
...
```

**Actualización**

La otra parte del problema ocurre porque dentro del método `uiAdmin()` estás creando una nueva instancia de la clase `ManejadorUsuario` en la línea

`ManejadorUsuario mUsuario=new ManejadorUsuario();`

Esta nueva instancia (`mUsuario`) no tiene ninguna relación con la utilizada en los otros métodos que mencionas.

Una forma de resolverlo es agregarla como parámetro al método `uiAdmin()`:

```
//Modifica la declaración del método
//            aquí   |
//                   V
public void uiAdmin(ManejadorUsuario mUsuario){
    ObtenerDatos oD=new ObtenerDatos();
    ManejadorCliente mCliente=new ManejadorCliente();
    ManejadorProducto mProducto=new ManejadorProducto();

    // y elimina esta línea completa
    //              |
    //              V
    ManejadorUsuario mUsuario=new ManejadorUsuario();

    ...
}
```

Luego en el método `autentificacion()`, modifica la línea donde invocas al método `uiAdmin()`

```
public void autentificacion(){

    //... código omitido para mantener el foco en el área de interés

    if(arregloUsuario.get(i).getRol()=="A"){
       ...
       // pasas la instancia de mUsuario
       //                 así  |
       //                      V
       iAdministrador.uiAdmin(mUsuario);
       ...
```

Ten en cuenta que si invocas el método `uiAdmin()` en otras partes del programa, este cambio provocará errores de compilación que debes corregir como lo muestro en  `autentificacion()`.

Como una recomendación adicional, pude observar que haces declaraciones de variables que no utilizas, si bien esto no tiene un efecto que se note facilmente, debes evitarlo porque repercute en el consumo de memoria de tu aplicación (por mencionar un efecto negativo).

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, pero creo que no me di a entender del todo, pero gracias a ti he solucionado uno de los problemas.

El problema principal era que al ingresar/registrar mas objetos Usuario para hacer el método autentificación es que no detecta los que ingrese, si quieres con mucho gusto te puedo pasar mis archivos para que entres todavía más en contexto, la verdad es que es mi proyecto final bimestral de mi colegio y quiero solucionar ese problema para tener la nota completa.

Comment: Entonces el problema principal era:
Tengo un método llamado agregarUsuario, en dónde lo uso exclusivamente para agregar un solo usuario administrador [A] cuando se ejecuta inmediatamente, luego tengo otro método llamado ingresarUsuario que se ubica en una clase ManejadorUsuario en dónde lo uso para ingresar usuario administradores [A] y cajeros [C], (Pero ese método lo invoco en una clase llamada InterfazAdministrador en un método llamado uiAdmin)...

Comment: ... Entonces cuando estoy en la clase InterfazAdminstrador tengo una interfaz en dónde tengo todos los demás métodos (esos métodos no importan), con una de los case del switch invoco a mi método ingresarUsuario de la clase ManejadorUsuario, me deja usarla correctamente, pero al salir del método uiAdmin para salir o reanudar el método autentificación no reconoce los objetos Usuario que ingrese anteriormente, hice la comprobación colocando un ciclo for que recorra el arregloUsuario pero no muestra nada, los toma como si no los ingrese, pero al volver a entrar en el método uiAdmin si aparecen :/.

Comment: Hola @OsmarOrtiz , por el momento necesito ver el método `uiAdmin` de la clase `InterfazAdministrador` para avanzar en la revisión que estoy haciendo. Por favor puedes editar la pregunta y agregarlo.

Comment: Claro, en este instante lo añado.

Comment: @OsmarOrtiz, acabo de editar mi respuesta con la solución a la otra parte del problema.

Comment: Acabo de hacer lo que me marcaste y no soluciono nada :/, sigue trabajando las listas por aparte, he puesto un `mostrarUsuario();` justo después de `pass=oD.texto();` y solo me muestra el objeto Usuario que había ingresado con anterioridad en mi clase Principal (con el método agregarUsuario de la clase ManejadorUsuario, que únicamente lo uso en la clase Principal para agregar un único objeto Usuario), pero cuando entro al método uiAdmin me muestra el usuario que ingrese ahí (con el método mostrarUsuario en la clase ManejadorUsuario).

Comment: Oye, si quieres puedo contactarte por algún medio como Twitter o otro medio que estés dispuesto a dar, no sé si te sería más cómodo, facilitaría la resolución, porque te podría pasar el archivo, este es mi proyecto final y se entrega mañana y me ocurrió este pequeño contratiempo.

Comment: @OsmarOrtiz, `mostrarUsuario();` no está en el código que compartiste en tu pregunta y `pass=oD.texto();` está en 2 métodos.

Comment: Te acabo de escribir un correo a la dirección que me indicaste.

Comment: te comento que no me llego nada :/, no están los correos que me mandaste.